# How to remove extension in makefile

Tags: makefile, substitution

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c ---
LDFLAGS = ---

SRCFILES := $(shell find ../ -name '*.c')
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
TESTFILE := $(patsubst %_test.c,%,$(SRCFILES))

all: $(TESTFILE)
$(TESTFILE): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@

all: $(OBJFILES)
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

For all:$(OBJFILES) and below, works perfectly fine. it creates all the object files I need however, I am having trouble creating the file test file. One of the SRC files is ABC_test.c, and the file I want to output is ABC_test (with no extension).

The ABC_test will have dependencies of all the OBJfiles. I think the way I have it set-up is correct but if it is not, please let me know. I am very new to makefiles.

I tried using substitution as you can see in the TESTFILE name. I believe my question is too specific and could not find help with a google search. Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that `patsubst` doesn't omit words from the result.  If the word matches the pattern then it is substituted.  If the word doesn't match the pattern then it's just emitted as-is.

So, if you have:

```
FOO = foo_1 foo_2 bar_1 bar_2

$(info $(patsubst foo%,FOO%,$(FOO))
```

then the output will be:

```
FOO_1 FOO_2 bar_1 bar_2
```

It will NOT be, as you seem to be expecting:

```
FOO_1 FOO_2
```

with the non-matching values left out.  If you want to *remove* words from the output you need to use the `filter` and `filter-out` functions.  So for example:

```
TESTFILE = $(patsubst %_file.c,%,$(filter %_test.c,$(SRCFILES)))
```